# Посчитать count по выборке внутри таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица Posts:

```
Id
Type
ParentId
```

Делаю запрос

```
select Id where Type = 1 order by Id desc limit 15
```

Требуется составить запрос, что бы в выборке было дополнительное значение count.
В ParentId могут быть Родительские Id.
Count это количество ParentId для данного Id

| Id | Type | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | null |
| 5 | 1 | null |
| 6 | 2 | 4 |

select Id, Count where Type = 1 .... должно выдавать такой результат

| Id | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 |

Comment: `count` чего должно быть в выборке?

Comment: @Zufir Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коррелированный подзапрос в списке вывода:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
       id,
       COALESCE( ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM test t2
                   WHERE t1.id = t2.parentid ), 0) `count`
FROM test t1
WHERE type = 1
```